# CloudFormation send back Lambda response from API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to deploy a REST API using CloudFormation but when accessing the endpoint I recieve a 503 error. I am guessing it has to do with the way I setup the method. It seems to miss the Method Response (comparing it to manually setting everything up) as the response body for 200 is empty while in the manual deployment it says `application/json`.

The Method resource I got looks like:

```
APIGateWayMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: GET
      ResourceId: !Ref APIGatewayResource
      RestApiId: !Ref APIGatewayRestAPI
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        Uri: !Sub
          - arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt MyLambda.Arn
```

How would I specify that I want the data from the `json.dumps()` inside the Lambda to be returned to the caller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the AWS_PROXY integration method, meaning that everything that is returned to the client from the API comes from your lambda function and not from your API Gateway configuration, so the lambda configuration would be more useful to see than the API Gateway integration.

That being said, an HTTP 503 from API Gateway usually means that a downstream service took too long to respond.
The first possibility is your lambda timing out before it is finished running. In which case you might have to increase the timeout or the allocated memory.
A second possibility is a timeout from the API Gateway configuration. However, this is by default at 29 or 30 seconds I think.

Comment: Yep, the API Gateway timeout is [30 seconds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html) and can't be changed. :(

Comment: You were correct. Running a test from within API Gateway revealed a naming error.